# Oracle Debug options DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP vs DBMS_DEBUG

Tags: oracle, debugging

Any Oracle ninjas out there that might illuminate me in comparing and determining differences (PROS/CONS) between **DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP** VS **DBMS_DEBUG**

I have DBMS_DEBUG working but hangs every now and then.
DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP requires asking the DB Admin and Network folks to do some changes, that might not happen.

Found tutorial/docs explaining the JDWP setups etc., but nothing that clearly says this (JDWP) or that (DBMS_DEBUG), is better due to this and that!

Thanks,
eVaz

Comment: [DBMS_DEBUG is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/release-changes.html#GUID-EDBEC906-B269-4C5B-A9FE-D5AADA61532B) from 12cR2, which is a bit of a con...

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/release-changes.html  (thanks @AlexPoole)

> The following features are deprecated in Oracle Database 12c Release 2
> (12.2), and may be desupported in a future release:
>
> Deprecation of the DBMS_DEBUG package
>
> **Use DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP instead.**